# Export from SQL to Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, export, ssms

I have a sql database will a lot of tables and records but I only want to export the first N rows in some of the tables. The SQL export wizard works but exports all of the table data which I do not want to do, I only want the first N rows.

How can I get around this? Thanks

Comment: I do not want to add anything into the sql database. I have tried temp tables but they do not seem to be picked up in the SQL export wizard

Comment: You can create stored procedure with parameter then call that stored procedure by MS-Access Pass Through query and save the query. Then append this query output to new tables in access.

Answer (score 1):

Create a straight *view* for each of these tables selecting `TOP N` records.

Then export the views.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the original sql server database, you could create a second sql server database, which only contains the views, which @Gustav suggested.

Those views then reference the tables of the original sql server database.

So you wouldn't have to touch the original database at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dump data From ALL tables in SQL Server to separate CSV Files.  Open PowerShell with Administrator Privileges (search for 'powershell', right click 'powershell.exe' and click 'Run as an Adminitrator').  In the windo that opens, run this code.

```
$server = "SERVERNAME\INSTANCE"
$database = "DATABASE_NAME"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()



# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\mssql\export\$($Row[0]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

[image]

Now, in Access, run the VBA code below (loop through all CSV files and import each to a table).

```
Function DoImport()

 Dim strPathFile As String
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

 ' Change this next line to True if the first row in CSV worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = True

 ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the CSV files
 strPath = "C:\your_path_here\"

 ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
 ' the data are to be imported

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       
       'DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
       DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
       
 ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()
 Loop

End Function
```

[image]

NOTICE: you can link to the file, like I am doing here, or you can import the file.  If you import the data, make sure you do a Compact and Repair after your import is done.  Access is notorious for bloating up to be quite huge after importing lots of data.